# Android NullPointerException on ValueAnimator.start()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-animation

I am using ValueAnimator to animate a View, but it throws a NullPointerException whenever I call start().

here is my stack trace after calling start() in my code:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.initAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:447)
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:495)
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:913)
        at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:923)
```

here is the part of my code that creates and calls animation:

```
    ValueAnimator va = new ValueAnimator();
    va.ofInt(somevalue, 0);
    va.setDuration(Game.ANIMATION_DURATION);
    va.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {//some code here
         }
         @Override
         public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {//some code here
         }

         @Override
         public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

         @Override
         public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
    });
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                  //some code here
         }
    });
    va.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    va.start();
```

Comment: What is somevalue in your code? Also, add a try-catch for your code at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the correct way to create an instance is like this:
`ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(someValue, 0);`. The `va.ofInt(...)` is doing nothing right now.

Comment: yep. because `ofInt` is a static method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use non-static access use

```java
ValueAnimator.setIntValues(int...)
```